# json-schema dynamic properties based on other properties and validate them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonschema

I have this schema to validate my object

```
{
  "required": ["description", "type", "properties", "element", "tests"],
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "primitive": {
      "type": ["string", "number", "boolean"]
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "error_message": { "$ref": "error_message.json" },
    "description": { "$ref": "description.json" },
    "tests": { "$ref": "tests.json" },
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["object"]
    },
    "properties": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "element": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    }
  }
}
```

*Now I want to dynamically validate that any new property introduced in the input must match the properties specified in the "properties" array.
Additionally, I want to ensure that all the specified properties in the "properties" array must be present in the input.*

for example:

##This is valid:

```
     {
            description: "text",
            type: "object",
            element: "something",
            tests: {
              pass: [{ "name": "John", "age": 30, "gender": "male" }],
              fail: [{ "name": "Bo", "age": 17, "gender": "thing" }]
            },
            properties: ["name", "age", "gender"],
            age: { range: { min: "1", max: "120"}},
            gender: { enum: ["male", "female"] },
            names: { range: { min: "3", max: "20" }}
          }
```

##These are invalid:

```
  {
            description: "text",
            type: "object",
            element: "something",
            tests: {
              pass: [{ "name": "John", "age": 30, "gender": "male" }],
              fail: [{ "name": "Bo", "age": 17, "gender": "thing" }]
            },
            properties: ["name", "age", "gender"],
            age: { range: { min: "1", max: "120"}},
            gender: { enum: ["male", "female"] },
            ##name here is missed
          }
```

```
  {
            description: "text",
            type: "object",
            element: "something",
            tests: {
              pass: [{ "name": "John", "age": 30, "gender": "male" }],
              fail: [{ "name": "Bo", "age": 17, "gender": "thing" }]
            },
            properties: ["name", "age", "gender"],
            age: { range: { min: "1", max: "120"}},
            gender: { enum: ["male", "female"] },
            # job here is extra 
            job: { range: { min: "3", max: "20" }}
          }
```

Comment: I am still a bit unclear but I assume the first in invalid too as "properties" lists "name" but the key is "names", additionally the third does not have a "name" key either. Other than that I have no idea how you are performing these validations and this question has no content that suggests the [tag:ruby] or [tag:ruby-on-rails] tags serve a purpose.

Comment: This is not something JSON Schema can express. Keywords can't be described in terms of input values.